# Is it possible to send additional HTTP headers to web services via New-WebServiceProxy

Tags: web-services, powershell

A web service I need to interact with (often manually for testing) requires an extra HTTP header on certain requests. Quick manual testing works quite great with PowerShell's `New-WebServiceProxy` but so far I haven't found an option to add another HTTP header to the request.

Is there something for that?

Answer (score 134):

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://yourURLhere -Headers @{"accept"="application/json"}
```

Introduced in [POSH 3.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx)

Comment: I got an error since `Accept` is a reserved header name.  I ended up using WebClient instead.

Comment: This does work in PowerShell, but only v4 and later. In v3, it throws an exception.

Comment: The question is about adding headers when using the cmdlet `New-WebServiceProxy` and not `Invoke-WebRequest`

Comment: I came here long after a search for Invoke-WebRequest headers on the command line. Multiple headers can be separated by a semi-colon:  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://exampleURL -Headers @{'x-caller-name' = 'CallerName';
'Content-Type' = 'application/json' ;
 }

Answer (score 25):

You could use .NET's web client from PowerShell.

```
> $webClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
> $webClient.Headers.add('accept','application/json')
> $webClient.DownloadString('http://yourURLhere')
```

Comment: That's a *lot* more complicated than just getting a proxy object with all the proper methods and types. If I'm just typing everything by hand including the JSON/XML then I can just use Fiddler and be done with it

Comment: You could always copy the Fiddler request to a text file and read that in from PowerShell to automate creating the headers, whichever approach you go with.

Comment: This is the answer for PS3 and below.

Comment: @davidhigh correction: for below PS3. PS3 does include the `-Headers` option.

Answer (score 15):

I am surprised this hasn't come up:

```
$uri = 'http://...'

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Accept','Application/Json')
$headers.Add('X-My-Header','...')

$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

For completeness, a reference to the headers property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, that's using a completely different method of accessing the web service. Of course, that's an option, but that wasn't what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

One more easy way to send Authorization and perform Get or Delete request in Loop

```
$orders=@("522536","522539")

foreach ($order in $orders){
    iwr "https://api.taxjar.com/v2/transactions/orders/$order" `
      -Method 'DELETE'`
      -Headers @{ 'Authorization' ='Token token="34625gdsgd74rghdg4"'}
}
```